# java user-defined array (and user-defined array size) returning [null, null, null, ...]

Tags: java, arrays, null, user-defined

This is my first question on this site, I'm running this on NetBeans 8.0.2 and trying to print out my user-defined array but it keeps returning null values. For example if you say there are 2 employees and enter both of their names, it will return [null, null]

How to fix this error? I'm a novice.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Tips_Calculation2 
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many employees for the week?: ");
    int numberOfEmps = scan.nextInt();

    // counter for the if statement that should return all employees from the array
    int counter = numberOfEmps;

    int[] nOEarray = new int[numberOfEmps];


    System.out.println("\nEnter names of workers up to the entered amount (" + numberOfEmps + "):");


    for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEmps; i++)
    {
        String nameCycler = scan.next();
        String[] namesArray = new String[i];

        if(counter == i)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Disregard import java.text.DecimalFormat as I plan to use this import later on in my code. Thank you in advance to anyone who is kind/smart enough to respond.

Comment: What's the point of `counter` as a separate variable? Just use `numberOfEmps`, or better yet, `nOEarray.length`.

Comment: He said _"I am a novice"_, he will find it useless in the future ;)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you never put your `nameCycler` to array. Second of all you create your `namesArray` every iteration which I think is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a brand new (full of `null`) array `namesArray` on *every pass* through the loop--and then never assigning anything to it. I think you're looking for something like this instead. Note that Java indexes from zero, not one.

```
String[] names = new String[numberOfEmps]

for(int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    names[i] = scanner.next();
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should initialise the array outside of your loop. Secondly, you forgot to set the name to the array value(s).

Try this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;

class Tips_Calculation2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("How many employees for the week?: ");
        int numberOfEmps = scan.nextInt();

        int[] nOEarray = new int[numberOfEmps];

        System.out.println("\nEnter names of workers up to the entered amount (" + numberOfEmps + "):");

        String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfEmps];

        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEmps; i++) {
            namesArray[i] = scan.next();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never assign  the name to the array and in every iteration you define the array new:

```
 String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfEmps];
 for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEmps; i++)
    {
        String nameCycler = scan.next();
        namesArray [i] = nameCycler ;
        if(counter == i)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Added comments in the code to point out changes.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("How many employees for the week?: ");
    int numberOfEmps = scan.nextInt();

    // removed 'nOEarray' and 'counter'

    if (numberOfEmps > 0) {
        System.out.println("\nEnter names of workers up to the entered amount (" + numberOfEmps + "):");

        // initializing 'namesArray' outside for loop.
        String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfEmps];
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmps; i++) { // initialized with 0 and updated condition with '<'
            namesArray[i] = scan.next(); // assigning value to 'i'th position of namesArray
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray)); // Printing array outside for loop
    }
}
```

Comment: Guaranteed `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for(int i = 1; i <= numberOfEmps; i++)
{
    String nameCycler = scan.next();
    String[] namesArray = new String[i];

    if(counter == i)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
    }
}
```

With

```
String[] namesArray = new String[numberOfEmps];
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfEmps; i++)
{
    namesArray[i] = scan.next();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
```

And see whether it works.

Answer (score -1):

"How to fix this error" not. This is not an error.

```
 String[] namesArray = new String[i]; // step one, you declare an array of Strings
  // which you don't initialize

        if(counter == i)
        {
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(namesArray));
//you print all the (non-initialized) elements of namesArray
//since you didn't initialize the elements, it takes the default value, which is null
        }
```

fill the elements of the array with Strings before trying to print them.